# WebScrapping with Selenium and BeaufitulSoup can't find anything

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I am trying to extract all the description in the links in the `class="publication u-padding-xs-ver js-publication"` of this website: https://www.sciencedirect.com/browse/journals-and-books?accessType=openAccess&accessType=containsOpenAccess

I tried both with BeautifulSoup and Selenium but I can't extract anything. You can see in the image below the result I got
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MTEk.png)

Here is the code I am using

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
ul = driver.find_element(By.ID, "publication-list")
print("Links")
allLi = ul.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "li")
for li in allLi:
    print("Links " + str(count) + " " + li.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing waits.
You have to wait for elements to become visible before accessing them.
The best approach to do that is with use of `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits.
The following code works

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://www.sciencedirect.com/browse/journals-and-books?accessType=openAccess&accessType=containsOpenAccess"
driver.get(url)
ul = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "publication-list")))
allLi = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "li")))
print(len(allLi))
```

the output is:

```
167
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks! I didn't know. Actually now I can easily get all the anchors with a specific class like this wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='anchor js-publication-title anchor-default']")), how can I get all the href?

Comment: Please open a new question for that